# How can I check if a browser's textareas are resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm going to attach custom resize handles if the browser does not make textareas resizable: how can I check if this is the case? (Without resorting to testing for specific browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, this seems to work:

```
if($(textarea).css('resize') != 'both'){
    // add custom resize handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding custom resize handles in all browsers. The advantage of this is that your site will look the same (or nearly the same) in all browsers. This site does this, using `resize:none;` in the css.

Comment: True, but the biggest difference in appearance is whether scrollbars are added by the browser (IE, Firefox), or not (Safari, Chrome)...

Comment: @James : What do you mean? A little experimentation I just did shows that in both Chrome and FF, scrollbars are not visible by default unless the text overflows. At any rate, you can control this through the `overflow` property.

Comment: Strange, for me firefox displays a scrollbar even if there is no overflow. :/